# R: Recoding multiple dummy variables into a single variable and replacing the corresponding dummy value with the variable name

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 14 mutually exclusive categories of call type all coded as dummy variables. Here is a small sample:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(MON1_12 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), WEEK1_53 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), AGENT_ID = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 10L), .Label = c("A129", "A360", 
"A407", "B891", "D197", "L145", "L722", "O518", "T443", "W764"
), class = "factor"), CallsHandled = c(1L, 4L, 2L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 
5L, 1L, 1L, 3L), CONTENT = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), CLAIMS = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
CREDIT_CARD = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
DEDUCT_BILL = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
HCREFORM = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("MON1_12", 
"WEEK1_53", "AGENT_ID", "CallsHandled", "CONTENT", "CLAIMS", 
"CREDIT_CARD", "DEDUCT_BILL", "HCREFORM"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

I want to combine each of the dummy variables into a single new variable called "QUEUE" that replaces the value of "1" with the name of the dummy variable its corresponding dummy variable. Here is an example of what this would look like:

```
dput(df2)
structure(list(MON1_12 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), WEEK1_53 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), AGENT_ID = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 10L), .Label = c("A129", "A360", 
"A407", "B891", "D197", "L145", "L722", "O518", "T443", "W764"
), class = "factor"), CallsHandled = c(1L, 4L, 2L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 
5L, 1L, 1L, 3L), QUEUE = structure(c(1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 5L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("CLAIMS", "CONTENT", "CREDIT_CARD", 
"DEDUCT_BILL", "HCREFORM"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("MON1_12", 
"WEEK1_53", "AGENT_ID", "CallsHandled", "QUEUE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Edit in response to having question marked down: This is what I had tried this afternoon on recommendation with a slightly different sample dataframe:

```
df$Queue <- as.factor(df$CONTENT + df$CLAIMS*2 + df$CREDIT_CARD*3 +  df$DEDUCT_BILL*4 + df$HCREFORM*5)
levels(df$Queue) <- c("CONTENT", "CLAIMS", "CREDIT_CARD","DEDUCT_BILL","HCREFORM")
View(df)
```

But I received a column of NA's in the Queue column. So, I recreated another sample dataset here. This dataframe is adequately representative of what I'll receive in reality, except I'll have about 40 variables and 2 million rows. When I run what I tried above on "df" above I get the following incorrect result:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(MON1_12 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), WEEK1_53 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), AGENT_ID = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 10L), .Label = c("A129", "A360", 
"A407", "B891", "D197", "L145", "L722", "O518", "T443", "W764"
), class = "factor"), CallsHandled = c(1L, 4L, 2L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 
5L, 1L, 1L, 3L), CONTENT = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), CLAIMS = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
CREDIT_CARD = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
DEDUCT_BILL = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
HCREFORM = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Queue = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("CONTENT", 
"CLAIMS", "CREDIT_CARD", "DEDUCT_BILL", "HCREFORM"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("MON1_12", 
"WEEK1_53", "AGENT_ID", "CallsHandled", "CONTENT", "CLAIMS", 
"CREDIT_CARD", "DEDUCT_BILL", "HCREFORM", "Queue"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I also tried:

```
df3 <- cbind(df[1:4], QUEUE = apply(df[5:9], 1, function(N) names(N)[as.logical(N)]))
```

but received the following error: "Error in data.frame("CLAIMS", character(0), character(0), "DEDUCT_BILL",  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0:

Comment: What did you try so far? Please share any attempt (edit your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `max.col` to get the column index that have a value of '1' in each row for columns 5 to 9.  (The 'df' example is not correct as most of the rows were all 0s.  The corrected one is below).

```
df$QUEUE <-  names(df)[-c(1:4)][max.col(df[-c(1:4)])]
```

Or you can do

```
df$QUEUE <-  names(df)[-(1:4)][(as.matrix(df[-(1:4)]) %*% 
                         seq_along(df[-(1:4)]))[,1]]
```

#### Update

Based on the edit dataset 'df', some rows are all '0's for the columns 5:9, and in the expected result, it is showed that 'QUEUE' as 'CONTENT'.  In that case, we can first modify the 'CONTENT' column to change the values where rows are all 0's and then apply either of the code above

```
 df$CONTENT[!rowSums(df[5:9])] <- 1
 df$QUEUE1 <-  names(df)[5:9][max.col(df[5:9])]
 df$QUEUE1
 #[1] "CLAIMS"      "CONTENT"     "CONTENT"     "DEDUCT_BILL" "CONTENT"    
 #[6] "CONTENT"     "CONTENT"     "CONTENT"     "CONTENT"     "CONTENT"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(MON1_12 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), WEEK1_53 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
AGENT_ID = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 10L), .Label = c("A129", "A360", 
"A407", "B891", "D197", "L145", "L722", "O518", "T443", "W764"
), class = "factor"), CallsHandled = c(1L, 4L, 2L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 
5L, 1L, 1L, 3L), CONTENT = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), CLAIMS = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), CREDIT_CARD = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0), DEDUCT_BILL = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
 HCREFORM = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0)), .Names = c("MON1_12", "WEEK1_53", 
"AGENT_ID", "CallsHandled", "CONTENT", "CLAIMS", "CREDIT_CARD", 
"DEDUCT_BILL", "HCREFORM"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks much for addressing another one of my questions.  For some reason when running your first suggestion I obtain a "QUEUE" column with names where there aren's any "1's" for that particular dummy variable, e.g., row 2 in column "QUEUE" displays "CONTENT", but the value for the "CONTENT" dummy variable is "0" for that same row so no name should result in row 2 column "QUEUE". Am I getting a different result than you?

Comment: @user3594490 My solution was based on the assumption that you have '1' in each of the rows for a single column.  In the first example you provided, there are rows with only 0's.  I don't know how you select the column name with that kind of a data.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @user3594490 Just looked at your edit dataset.  Here, the rows with 0 are named as 'CONTENT`.  Is that the condition?

Comment: @user3594490 I think the `QUEUE` value in the expected output is not correct for the 4th element.  It should be `DEDUCT_BILL`.  Updated the post

Comment: in my real dataset (to my knowledge) there should never be a row with a zero across all the dummy coded columns. I only included 5 of 14 total columns in the sample. There should be a "1" in one and only one of those Dummy columns. In my sample there are zeros in the CONTENT column for every row. So only if there were a "1" would I want  "CONTENT" to appear in the "QUEUE" column for that respective row.

Comment: @user3594490 I corrected the code and got the expected result as you showed except for the 4th element which I think is a typo

Comment: you are correct. The expected output is not accurate for the sample that I posted. It was for the sample I intended to post earlier.

Comment: @user3594490 If the original dataset have a single 1 in each of the row, my initial code should work

Comment: Yes your edit works! I think I have been throwing others off with the errors in my expected output. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

This should produce the desired result:

```
df2 <- cbind(df[1:4], QUEUE = apply(df[5:9], 1, function(N) names(N)[as.logical(N)]))
```

provided that only one and exactly one of the dummy variables is 1 in any of the rows (which is not true in your original sample of `df`).

**Explanation:** df[1:4] selects the columns one through four to be preserved in the output. It is then column bound to `QUEUE` using `cbind` function. `QUEUE` is obtained by iterating through the dummy variables (columns five through nine), row-wise over the data set `df` and selecting the column-name that contains the value one.

Comment: I did apparently post an old version the df but when I opened it in R I still didn't see duplicate 1's in any of the 5 dummy queues. They should in reality always be mutually exclusive for each row. There are a few without any 1's, which is what I wanted to change in the sample I intended to upload. But this dataframe is likely what I'll get in reality with some queues that have no calls for certain agents.  I tried this code you provided but received the error I edited above.

Comment: thanks this also works on my sample but I'm getting an error with my large dataset for some reason. Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 267757, 16. I'm not sure why I'm getting a differing number of rows.

Comment: @user3594490, Check `any(rowSums(df[5:9]) != 1)` is not `FALSE` or `NA`.

Comment: I finally discovered that even after using the following commands when importing the data: mydata<-read.csv("mydata.csv",stringsAsFactors= TRUE,strip.white=TRUE) I'm getting additional rows on my dataframe in R that have NA values for most of the columns. I think prob is with added spaces in the empty cells of the excel file I'm receiving. Trying to find best way to delete any and all empty cells when importing.